# Why IE8 blocking a pop-up window which appears in IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am working on a client server application,in which we open client on our pc by URL:http:\[ip of server]:[port no].
My application start by using the URL mentioned in IE, and one pop-up comes in which we perform every action of the apllication and original window we can close as they are only for starting. One of my customer is using IE8 and he is facing a problem in which after clicking on save to bookmark the pop-up is not coming and hence not able to save. In IE7 pop-up as an another window is coming and giving the option to save.

What is blocking the pop-up? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: By Java DYM [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Is `ip of server` on the local area network where you develop?

Comment: Maybe stupid question.... is running your client IE8 compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1):

For popups the same goes as for spam email - as the popup developers get smarter, so do the popup blocker developers. As such it makes sense that newer browser versions are stricter in the rules they evaluate to determine when a popup needs to be blocked.

All modern browsers follow the same rules, that all boil down to **"popups are only allowed if the user directly initiated them"**. This means that they guard execution paths, and every call to `window.open` is caught by the popup blocker unless it can be **directly** traced to a user action. And as popup developers invented more inventive ways to make a browser think the user initiated it, popup blockers got more inventive in detecting them.

A quite plausible explanation is also that you are developing on a LAN, where IE applies lower security settings by default, allowing more user popups automatically. We cannot see that from your post though.